# Change my datepicker format from (YYYY/MM/DD) to (YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: php

My datepicker format is (YYYY/MM/DD) , my sql only reads (YYYY-MM-DD) format
My system only accepts that specific format or the show report wont work properly.
Is there anything that i could add , so when i click the specific date the format will be (YYYY-MM-DD)

What should i do please help me.
H
Thanks

This is my php file

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>


<?php include('session.php'); ?>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php include('navbar.php'); ?>
<div style="height:50px;"></div>
<div id="page-wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <h1 class="page-header">Inventory Report</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="invTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

<center>
 <form action="total_inventory.php" method="post">
<p>From: <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="E.G.(2018-01-14)" name="dayfrom" required pattern="[0-9]{4}+[0-9]+[0-9]" id="datepicker">
To: <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="E.G.(2018-02-11)" name="dayto" required pattern="[0-9]{4}+[0-9]+[0-9]" id="datepicker1">


  <input type="submit" value="Show Report" name="salesbtn" ></form>

</center>

                        <th class="hidden"></th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>User</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

<?php include('script.php'); ?>
<?php include('modal.php'); ?>
<?php include('add_modal.php'); ?>
<script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside the jQuery script code just paste the code.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' 
});
```

*Note : You can change this format as you required. just edit code as per your requirement.*

Answer (score 2):

Add the date picker formate in your date picker code like below.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

use the class for all date fields like this:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify through configuration the way you call your datepicker as follows. I see you are using jquery-ui datepicker.

This should work:

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
  });
```